# Telerik RadGrid not showing any data in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I'm trying to make a really simple grid for some data on an ASP.NET page, but clearly I'm doing something wrong here. First of all, let me show you the grid I have on my clientside:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlDoorAccess" Visible="False">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upnlDoorAccess" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
        <ContentTemplate>    
            <tel:RadGrid runat="server" ID="gvDoorAccess" AllowSorting="false" AllowPaging="false"
                CssClass="col-sm-12 noPadding" MasterTableView-CssClass="table table-hover table-header-bg table-striped no-footer tableHeaderBorder"
                OnNeedDataSource="radDoorAccess_NeedDataSource" OnItemDataBound="radDoorAccess_ItemDataBound">
                <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false" TableLayout="Fixed" Caption="" FilterExpression="" AllowNaturalSort="false" DataKeyNames="Month" NoMasterRecordsText="No records to Display">
                    <Columns>
                        <tel:GridBoundColumn DataField="DoorName" HeaderText="Door Name" UniqueName="DoorName"></tel:GridBoundColumn>
                    </Columns>
                </MasterTableView> 
            </tel:RadGrid>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

So I wanna test the grid by only showing 1 column (DoorName), but so far it's not showing anything. Next is the server side code:

The DoorAccess property will fire up `Controller.GetDoorAccess(CurrentUser.Id)` when the Object Memorystore is empty and return me a DataTable object which I will return and eventually store into a DataSource property later on.

```
protected List<DoorAccess> DoorAccess
{
    get
    {
        if (omsDoorAccess.DataItem == null || omsDoorAccess.DataItem.GetType() != typeof(List<Option>)) omsDoorAccess.DataItem = Controller.GetDoorAccess(CurrentUser.Id);

        return (omsDoorAccess.DataItem as List<DoorAccess>);
    }
    set
    {
        omsDoorAccess.DataItem = value;
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadTab_DoorAccess();
    }
}

private void LoadTab_DoorAccess()
{
    // Future implementation
    ReloadTab_DoorAccess();
}

private void ReloadTab_DoorAccess()
{
    gvDoorAccess.DataBind();

    upnlDoorAccess.DataBind();
    upnlDoorAccess.Update();
}

protected void radDoorAccess_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as RadGrid).DataSource = DoorAccess; 
    // DoorAccess holds 128 items
}

protected void radDoorAccess_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType != GridItemType.Item && e.Item.ItemType != GridItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
       // Do stuff in the future
    }
}
```

So what exactly is going on here? There is probably something obvious I'm missing, but right now I don't see it.

If this question makes no sense, could you show me a block of code that would help me create a simple grid?

Comment: Having your grid inside of an UpdatePanel is going to seriously hamper debugging.  Try taking it out of the UpdatePanel and see if you get a useful error or information.  Such as, is a breakpoint hit in the NeedDataSource event?  Is a breakpoint hit in the ItemDataBound event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have `AutoGeneratedColumns="False"`, a single column declared with the `DataField="DoorName"`, and `DataKeyName="Month"`.

When using Advanced DataBinding the datasource you are binding to must match the schema in the RadGrid unless you are using AutoGenerateColumns.

Without seeing your controller code, I think the issue is with the above Markup. There is no way for the grid to bind the single column with the `DataField` of "DoorName" to the `DoorAccess` object using the `DataKeyName` of "Month"(not knowing where "Month" is coming from). Make sure the `DataKeyName` property contains a unique value from the `DoorAccess` object and that the column `DataField` is equal to any property in the `DoorAccess` object.

ASPX:

```
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource">
         <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" CommandItemDisplay="Top">
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Id" UniqueName="MyId" HeaderText="My Id"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Value" UniqueName="Value" HeaderText="My Value"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>      
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

C#:

```
public class MyDataModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}


protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
   List<MyDataModel> datasource = new List<MyDataModel>();
   for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
   datasource.Add(new MyDataModel {
        Id = i,
        Value = "Value" + i.ToString
    });
   }

   ((RadGrid)sender).DataSource = datasource;

}
```

I would first try with autogenerated columns on to make sure valid data is being returned from the NeedDataSource event, and then make sure your `DataKeyNames` and `DataFields` are valid properties. Additionally as @Seano666 said, because your grid is in an `UpdatePanel` any errors the RadGrid throws due to incorrect formatting will be suppressed.

Comment: This seems like a valid working solution. However I'm getting the following error: `No property or field 'Filter' exists in type 'MyDataModel'`. I'm getting this error with any class I try to use though. I'm clueless about this.

Comment: Just noticed that when I don't add items to my datasource in the forloop, I'm not getting the error anymore. Even when I try datasource.Add(null); I'll still get the error message in the previous comment.

Comment: I added `EnableLinqExpressions="false"` to my radgrid and now the radgrid is showing perfectly!

Comment: Interesting issue. Glad you found the solution. The above code worked fine on my end. I believe the cause is that when binding to certain objects where the `DataType` is not known(such as an `EntityDataSource` or other Controller), the `Linq` doesn't render properly. That's why disabling `LinqExpressions` solves the problem. [A similar Error](http://www.telerik.com/forums/no-property-or-field-recordid-exists-in-type-entitydatasourcewrapper)

Comment: Alternatively, I see that in the `MasterTableView` node you have `FilterExpression=""` if you removed that, my guess is the problem may go away

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't help. Still get the same error, but nice thinking!